# Convert list of string representations of sentences into vocabulary set

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, nlp

I have a list of string representations of sentences that looks something like this:

```
original_format = ["This is a question", "This is another question", "And one more too"]
```

I want to convert this list into a set of unique words in my corpus. Given the above list, the output would look something like this:

```
{'And', 'This', 'a', 'another', 'is', 'more', 'one', 'question', 'too'}
```

I've figured out a way to do this, but it takes a very long time to run. I am interested in a more efficient way of converting from one format to another (especially since my actual dataset contains >200k sentences).

FYI, what I'm doing right now is creating an empty set for the vocab and then looping through each sentence (split by spaces) and unioning with the vocab set. Using the **original_format** variable as defined above, it looks like this:

```
vocab = set()
for q in original_format:
    vocab = vocab.union(set(q.split(' ')))
```

Can you help me run this conversion more efficiently?

Comment: How do you store your dataset? As in what format is it in initially?

Comment: It's full sentence strings in a SQL database. So I have a column "Questions" and cell in that column might look like "Is this a question?". I'm pulling to python via pandas and then converting the dataframe of questions to this format.

Comment: Oh then there is definitely a faster way to find the unique words.  Probably best approach is to just select all distinct words from your SQL column.

Comment: Try this SQL query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d8a55/1 Will avoid having to transform your data at all.

Comment: This is awesome, chrisz. Thanks for showing me that query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain` with `set`. This avoids nested `for` loops and `list` construction.

```
from itertools import chain

original_format = ["This is a question", "This is another question", "And one more too"]

res = set(chain.from_iterable(i.split() for i in original_format))

print(res)

{'And', 'This', 'a', 'another', 'is', 'more', 'one', 'question', 'too'}
```

---

Or for a truly functional approach:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import methodcaller

res = set(chain.from_iterable(map(methodcaller('split'), original_format)))
```

Comment: using itertools.chain() runs ~11% faster than mapping the split function. Both of these methods run faster than the set comprehension. Thanks, jpp!

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple set comprehension:

```
{j for i in original_format for j in i.split()}
```

Output:

```
{'too', 'is', 'This', 'And', 'question', 'another', 'more', 'one', 'a'}
```